# Get measurement values from point along the route Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, linear-referencing

I have two shape files, one is a route shapefile with polyline and have measurement values. The other one is point with coordinates but no measurement values. I am trying to snap the points to closest route and get measurement of the route that snapped in(please see picture). [image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the tool that you should investigate (as per the duplicate): https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/locate-features-along-routes.htm